# Train model for price prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to make stock predictor, i know that model which i will create, won't be great, but nonetheless. First off below i will add code that formate X and Y. X contains stocks prices for 10 days, Y contains answers(prices for next days).

```py
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
from sys import exit
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense 



with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/tickers.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  tickers_list = eval(json.loads(f.read()))['tickers'][:100] # list of tickers


X = []
Y = []


for ticker in tickers_list:
   stock = yf.download(ticker,'1990-01-01','2019-12-31')['Adj Close'].values
   for i in range(len(stock)):
     try:
       stock[i+11]
     except:
       continue
     X.append(stock[i:i+10])
     Y.append([stock[i+11]])
X = np.array(X) #price for 10 days
Y = np.array(Y) #price for next day
```

After that i wrote code for creating model.

```py
X_train = np.expand_dims(X, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=64,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=64))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')

print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

But when i ran code above, i got error.

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_17: expected shape=(None, None, 1), found shape=[None, 1, 10]
```

How to fix it?
Thank u.

**Note**
If u have any suggestions that could make my research better, pls write me here.

Comment: what's the output of `X_train.shape` ?

Comment: Output of X_train.shape is (474299, 1, 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
X_train = np.expand_dims(X, 2) # 2 instead of 1
```

Comment: Thank u,  do u have any suggestions for me that could improve my model? After the first epoch loss is nan.

Comment: if loss is nan, check if you have Nan in your dataset and remove them

Comment: I won't accept ur answer for 30mins, i will be waiting for suggestions. Ur answer has resolved my problem.

Comment: @BDouchet,What do u think. Technically, should my model work?

Comment: try reducing number of LSTM layers (start from one). 4 layers may be unstable

Comment: @BDouchet, if loss is nan, check if you have Nan in your dataset and remove them. How to do it? I'm new in datascience.

Comment: @Andrey, loss is still nan. model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=64,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(units=64))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

Comment: run `numpy.isnan(X_train).any()`, `numpy.isnan(Y).any()`

Comment: output for each is:
False
False

Comment: try `model.fit(X_train[:1000], Y[:1000])`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this function to create a time series dataset. Yours, including the error handling, seems suboptimal. This function is coming from a past version of the official Tensorflow documentation. Besides, it seems like you are concatenating a bunch of time series one after the other, which makes no sense.

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                    target_size, single_step=False):
    data, labels = [], []
    start_index = start_index + history_size
    if end_index is None:
        end_index = len(dataset) - target_size
    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        indices = np.arange(i-history_size, i)
        data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
        if single_step:
            labels.append(dataset[i + target_size])
        else:
            labels.append(dataset[i:i + target_size])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

Then, you won't even face the problem you're having. On top of that, please note that you do not need to print `model.summary()`, calling this method automatically prints it. Here's a full working example with the function I provided:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

stock = yf.download('aapl','1990-01-01','2019-12-31')['Adj Close'].values

def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                    target_size, single_step=False):
    data, labels = [], []
    start_index = start_index + history_size
    if end_index is None:
        end_index = len(dataset) - target_size
    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        indices = np.arange(i-history_size, i)
        data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
        if single_step:
            labels.append(dataset[i + target_size])
        else:
            labels.append(dataset[i:i + target_size])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

X, y = univariate_data(stock, 0, len(stock) - 1, 10, 1, True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=8,return_sequences=True,
                               input_shape=(10, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=8,return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=8,return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=8))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X, y, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

```
7547/7547 [==============================] - 12s 2ms/sample - loss: 286.5788
```

Comment: How to predict something?
aapl = np.array(list(yf.download('AAPL','2020-11-25','2020-12-10')['Adj Close'].values))
aapl = np.expand_dims(aapl, 1)
model.predict(aapl) gives me Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1]

Comment: If you make test data, you have to pass it through the function as well

Comment: Btw I'm pretty sure you're concatenating several time series one after the other, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: what are u taking about? I know that my model won't be great for its task.

Comment: Seems like u know much about AI, could u suggest me the best way for creating text generation model? I would use Embedding, GRU, and final Dense layer with x neurons, where x equals size of vocabulary. But i don't think that this model will work great. I'm locking forward for ur advice and hope that you will tell me something new or some advanced architecture for my task. Thank you!